# How to create a multi-language survey

Tags: internationalization, google-drive-api, google-forms

**I'm currently creating a survey on Google Form and I need to make it in 4 languages so the result of each questions are not separated depending on the language selected by the user. *(so we can have graphical results of each responses without taking language into account)***

This raises different questions:

1- Should I create different forms from the beginning *(one for each language)* OR is it better to merge all languages surveys into one & only google form linking questions by possible script/else?

2- What would be the best script to allow adding questions to the survey in the future while keeping the most accurate graph results?

3- Is it possible to give only one link to people so they decide in which language they want to take the survey? *(maybe creating one form for the only purpose of choosing language, then re-direct to appropriate form?)*

I really checked & couldn't find which way to create a multi-langual survey on Google Form... *(if needed I will separate each questions but they are pretty linked to each other...)*

Comment: My understanding with Google Form is they're integrated with Drive/Sheets.  So I think there's no way of implementing a Google Form with i18n. You'll have to create 4 Google Forms for each language and just merge the 4 forms later (better if you can specify it as a tab so for each language and not a separate form)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.
First, add a radio button question to allow the user to select their preferred language.

Then, create four sections in the form, each for one language.

Next, click on the three dots and select "Go to section based on answer". Make different options "redirect" to different language sections.

[image: Pic]